# How can it be that Java is NOT type safe in a particular situation?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, spring-data-jpa

Today I found a **very very weird behavior** of the JVM, a (normally type-safe) `List<Date>` did actually hold a `List<MyObject>` at runtime!

I wonder how that ever could happen, but couldn't find anything in the web.

That's the situation:
I'm working with `Spring Data JPA 1.2.0` on a `JBoss EAP 6.0 Server` with `JRE 1.6.0_18-b07`.

By mistake, in a `Spring Data JPA Repository` class there was written a wrong result type in the `@Query` expression. It should have been:

```
  @Query("select distinct trunc(record.orderDateTime) from MyType record [...]" )
  public List<Date> getOrderDates(...);
```

But was:

```
  @Query("select record from MyType record [...]" )
  public List<Date> getOrderDates(...);
```

So, the aim was to load a list of dates (`java.util.Date`), which works fine if the query is properly defined as in the first code snippet.

But that coding mistake led to the following result:
At runtime, there actually WAS a `List<MyType>` returned, even though the method's signature defines a `List<Date>`. Also in my model an attribute of `List<Date>` was/contained a `List<MyType>`. I debugged it and couldn't believe my eyes!
I could even write the content of this list to a JSP (I only recognized this weird behavior because a JSP couldn't be displayed any more due to a Spring Expression Language error occuring with the attempt to type match from `MyType` to `Date`, which of course had to crash).

Hell, shall I now loose my believe in the type-safety of Java?

Has anybody ever had such a problem?

Does an explanation for this exist?

And can I do anything to fix that or is it a general issue? Maybe another version of the JRE, JBOSS, ...?

Comment: Parameterized types, and all the stuff built around them, are not supported by the JVM -- it's just compiler "sugar".  I'm not surprised that it's not "airtight".

Answer (score 11):

> I wonder how that ever could happen, but couldn't find anything in the web.

It happens because generics are *mostly* a compile-time-only feature. Metadata is maintained in terms of a class's type parameters, fields etc... but at execution time, type arguments are (mostly) lost. For example:

```
Object x = new ArrayList<String>();
Object y = new ArrayList<Integer>();
System.out.println(x.getClass() == y.getClass()); // True
```

The JVM can't tell the difference - which is why you'll get a warning when you try to cast:

```
// At execution time, this cast will *really* only check for List
List<String> dodgyCast = (List<String>) y;
```

For the *most* part, the compiler keeps "regular" code using generics safe. But when you have things like ORMs providing values via reflection or dynamic byte code, all of that safety goes out of the window.

Comment: Stupid question: In the case of X.getClass and y.getClass, wouldn't it be because they're both ArrayLists as their class, and the type inside of them (The type of object they hold), would be one more level down? Therefore, x.getClass() == y.getClass() may be true, but x.get(1).getClass() == y.get(1).getClass() would return false. It's like looking at a house and saying they're identical on the outside, even if their layouts inside are totally different, isn't it?

Comment: @Gyhth using your analogy, it's not the house layout that's different, but the people who lives inside them. They behave the same, have the same components, are used the same way, but people inside of them are different. I.e., `X` and `Y`are the same, no matter what they store.

Comment: @Gyhth: No, not really. If you ask the same questions in .NET, for example, you find that a generic collection really *knows* about its element type. You really *can't* have a field of type `List<String>` which is actually a `List<SomeOtherType>`, because they're two different types at the runtime level. The two parameterized types *are different*, because the type arguments are present at execution. It's the fact that they're missing at execution time in Java which is the problem.

Answer (score 5):

Sadly, that kind of thing can happen because of [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). The type you set at your collection is only checked at compilation time, not runtime.

The thing is that your query is not compiled, so there's no way Java can know what kind of objects it will return. To avoid this kind of behaviour, I always create tests of my queries.